# How to change jQuery parameters when viewing page with responsive design from mobile device?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, galleriffic

I'm using the Galleriffic Galley plugin (http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/) to show slideshows in my site.

Many parameters for this are defined in JQuery.  Since my site is responsive, I want to change some of these parameters so that the page shows differently for mobile.

At the bottom of my page I have the following code, and I want to change the 'numThumbs' from 18 to 6.

What way would I achieve this?

Ty!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
        $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '100%', 'float' : 'left'});
        $('div.content').css('display' , 'block');

        // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
        // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
        var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.67;
        $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li').opacityrollover({
            mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
            mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
            fadeSpeed:         'fast',
            exemptionSelector: '.selected'
        });

        // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
        var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
            delay:                     2500,
            numThumbs:                 18,
            preloadAhead:              10,
            enableTopPager:            true,
            enableBottomPager:         true,
            maxPagesToShow:            7,
            imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
            controlsContainerSel:      '#controls',
            captionContainerSel:       '#caption',
            loadingContainerSel:       '#loading',
            renderSSControls:          true,
            renderNavControls:         true,
            playLinkText:              'Play Slideshow',
            pauseLinkText:             'Pause Slideshow',
            prevLinkText:              '&lsaquo; Prev',
            nextLinkText:              'Next &rsaquo;',
            nextPageLinkText:          'Next &rsaquo;',
            prevPageLinkText:          '&lsaquo; Prev',
            enableHistory:             false,
            autoStart:                 false,
            syncTransitions:           true,
            defaultTransitionDuration: 900,
            onSlideChange:             function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
                // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
                this.find('ul.thumbs').children()
                    .eq(prevIndex).fadeTo('fast', onMouseOutOpacity).end()
                    .eq(nextIndex).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
            },
            onPageTransitionOut:       function(callback) {
                this.fadeTo('fast', 0.0, callback);
            },
            onPageTransitionIn:        function() {
                this.fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I would use Modernizr: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: I was hoping to avoid something like that!  Thanks anyways.  I may try it out!

Comment: if you're looking for a JS solution try: `if (navigator.userAgent.match(/mobileplatform/i)` replace mobile platform with 'Andriod', etc. Also, you can use '||' to check for different OS

Answer (score 0):

From— [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

You could try something like this:

```
  var isMobile = false;

  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    isMobile = true;
  }

  var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
        delay:                     2500,
        numThumbs:                 isMobile ? 18 : 6,
        preloadAhead:              10.....
```